# Return date, hours,minutes and seconds included from function

Tags: sql, plsql

My functions looks as below, but it does not work. I can't really figure out what. Tried to return "sysdate" as well, help would be much appreciated.

I want it to display hours, minutes and seconds, not just a date!

```
create or replace function get_date
return date
is 
begin
return sysdate('YYYY-MM-DD: HH24:MI:SS') + 7;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want:

```
return sysdate + 7
```

if you want to add 7 days to the current date.

Comment: I want to include hours, minutes and seconds as well

Comment: @kaktusräv They are included automatically. `sysdate` doesn't just contain the date, it has the time as well.

Comment: right, but when I call the function it returns "2013-10-17" so it does not print out the time.

Comment: @Gordon's answer will return what you want, but if you want to format that value differently, then you should format it in the calling routine using to_char.

Comment: No, formatting is not an issue, except when it is. Your function is returning the date and time portions. You are just displaying it (formatting it) in a manner that omits the time portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you'll have to change your return type to a varchar2)

```
return to_char(sysdate + 7, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Or use a timestamp return type