# Return Date got no hour and minutes returned

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

This is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DATE(P_DAYS IN  NUMBER) RETURN DATE AS
  V_DATE DATE;
BEGIN
  V_DATE := SYSDATE+P_DAYS;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(V_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
  RETURN V_DATE;
END;
/
```

My output:

```
GET_DATE(2)
-----------
2015-03-12
2015-03-12 19:26:14
```

How do i get minutes, hours and seconds returned ? i want the answer to be like the dbms_output does...

Comment: Use `to_char()` to convert the date to  a string and include all the elements you want.

Comment: I have tried but not succeded.. Can you show me an example?


V_DATE := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+P_DAYS, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

It dont work..

Comment: v_date is a DATE type, not a char.  There is no conversion needed.  Please show how you got the output.

Comment: I Got this when i run it:

01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: i am calling it GET_DATE(2)

Comment: It's really anoying problem.. i have been stuck on this problem for couple days.. Can someone help me? :P

Comment: The output you're displaying doesn't make sense.  If you're just calling `get_date(2)`, only one value would be returned.  How are you getting two rows of output?  Are you, perhaps, saying that the first line is the output you are getting and the second is the output that you want?

Comment: In the code i have DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE thats why i got

2015-03-12 19:26:14

and from the returned function i got:

2015-03-12

Just showing what i want from the returned V_DATUM should be like the dbms_output.put_line with HOURS and MINUTES

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR(GET_DATE(2), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;

Comment: But i am not allow to do that.. i should just use SELECT GET_DATE(2)
FROM DUAL;

that's the assignment..

Comment: Does someone got any clue?

Comment: `Does someone got any clue?` - Do you really think that's appropriate? Do you think it will motivate people to help you?

Comment: Sigh ... the same homework assigment as http://stackoverflow.com/q/28971397/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DATE(p_days IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    v_date VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    v_date := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + p_days, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
    RETURN v_date;
END;
/
```

Comment: Your function was working from the beginning. All you were doing was displaying the date in a way that omitted the time portion. But it was always there.